# Why am I getting an "License checkout" error in DS-5?

Tags: eclipse, arm, license-key, ds-5

I try to compile the TrustZone example provided by `examples/Bare-metal_examples_ARMv7.zip` in DS-5 v5.21.1(latest version) and then I get this

> License checkout for feature compiler5 with version 5.0201503 has been denied by Flex back-end. Error code: -9

I have already viewed [INFOCENTER](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka16372.html) but error code in that page is -7 while my error code is -9. Besides, I am sure I get the license correctly added, and DS-5 has validated and accepted that license.

The license I'm using is a 30-day Ultimate Edition License(Evaluation), can it only be compiled with a formal Ultimate Edtion license or I did anything wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DS-5 is a commercial software product - I suggest you ask ARM support.

Comment: Yes, I have asked for help in their community but I didn't receive any answer before I ask here. Luckily, I just got an answer and I will modify this question soon. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TgnYang, You may want to answer your own question, rather than modifying the question. That will help other programmers who face the same situation :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Trouble shooting node-locked license issues](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4128.html) page in the [infocenter](http://infocenter.arm.com), -9 error indicates `"Invalid host. The hostid of this system does not match the hostid specified in the license file."` The [same](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4128.html) page lists common problems and ways to solve them.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the delay.